# UL certification requirements

Tags: pcb, poe, stepper-driver, certification, ul

I'm designing a circuit board for a large industrial product which is intended to be UL certified, so the boss wants as many individual submodules to be UL certified as possible, including mine. The problem is, certification seems to be an impenetrable maze for someone who isn't an expert or doesn't have significant experience; every standard is locked behind a paywall, and there are no clear guides to which standards a given product even needs to meet in the first place. CE isn't quite as bad, a bit of googling tells me as long as my board is safe and doesn't put out much EMI, I should be good.

The board is a Power-over-Ethernet PD, the sole function of which is driving some stepper motors. I'm just trying to get some idea of what I need to take into account when designing the thing to give it a decent chance of passing certification.

In general, how is someone starting any new design supposed to find out what they need to take into account without paying large sums of money?

Comment: Many UL specs have IEC equivalents that are cheaper to purchase. But knowing which specs you need to meet is the first battle. If you don't have an in-house expert, you may need to hire an outside consultant to guide you through it.

Comment: Do you have access to a library that has the standards available?

Comment: @ThePhoton that is what we're looking at, it just seems like a rather large expense for this early in the process

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I don't believe so

Comment: Maybe your boss will change his mind when s/he sees the price tag. Or maybe s/he'll realize it's less cost to do it right the first time than to try to fix it later.

Comment: *"CE isn't quite as bad, a bit of googling tells me **as long as my board is safe and doesn't put out much EMI**, I should be good."* I think that the same **over-simplification** applies for UL. But both UL and CE require more than this over-simplification. In case of CE, check reliable sources like the [site of the European Commission](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/ce-marking/manufacturers_en) or hire a consultant just like suggested for UL.

Comment: India has a freedom of information act and all specs are copied and free but generally SELV no problem <50Vdc but if AC on board. let us know

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 There won't be any AC; all power will be provided via PoE, specifically the 802.3bt standard, but this will likely be over 50V. The spec states anywhere between 42 and 57VDC on the PD side, and cables will likely be fairly short

Comment: under 75Vdc directives https://ec.europa.eu/growth/sectors/electrical-engineering/lvd-directive_en   Unfortunately cost of learning can be high too even If I sent you all the specs to sort out

Comment: resource https://www.intertek.com/iot/

Comment: Quiet often it is the *buyer* who will be placing demands on YOU for various UL and/or ISO certifications. Combined they can effectively double the cost of your product due to RoHS requirements, special solder, UL rated parts, ISO rated test equipment, product documentation, etc.

Comment: @Sparky256 so rather than it being a case of "If you have a device of category A, it must meet standards XYZ", it's more like "If you have a device of category A, there are several standards XYZ which are applicable if required, but not necessary"?

Comment: A great deal of good advice above. Here is a little more info. There are 18 laboratories who are approved by OSHA for safety testing/certification. UL has the most notoriety because they coordinate the safety specs, but they are by no means the only one. For example the oldest lab in this area is Met Labs. BTW: I have found UL to be difficult to work with and Met Labs to be much easier. We have a small electronics system in a metal chassis, powered from 120 VAC. Met Labs cost to certify: $19,000.00. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an example UL 1449 editions 3 and 4 cover industrial and residential surge suppression devices in the USA. Because of hazards they must be under UL and ISO regulations. In this case UL is about technical details and using UL approved parts such as X and Y rated capacitors for line to neutral and neutral to ground filtering. RoHS standards require lead-free solder.

ISO is more about documentation of both devices and the equipment used to test them. Then you have documentation about the documentation under a document control supervisor. It will drive you bonkers to implement this.

I would say to contact UL, FCC and ISO to find out if your product is under agency control of any kind. RF emitting devices have to follow FCC guidelines such that the container limits emissions to a stated level.

An exception would be DIY stuff not directly line connected and not emitting any radiation or RF noise or high voltage (shock hazard) or high current (burn hazard). But if you build and ship in large quantities it would behove you to analyse what the dangers are and any emissions and put a disclaimer on the product. Labels are a form of self-disclaimer such as "HIGH VOLTAGE", "SHOCK HAZARD" and "BURN HAZARD". This can fend off malpractice attorneys who would tear you to pieces if someone was injured by your product. By the way surge suppression devices must have all of the above labels and disclaimers about miss-use of product.

Before building anything for mass shipping I would get in touch with an attorney who can hire a pion to look into the myriad things that can bite you later on. You seriously need to get your ducks in a row before you ship anything that you or your employees built. Manufacturing can be an expensive business with lots of up-front cost, so consider the legal research worth it.